# How to add headers on a 302 redirect in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webclient, session-cookies, http-status-code-302

Basically I'm writing some code which does an internal webclient request, gets all the headers and then I want to add those headers to a `Redirect()` call via a controller.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Did you find out if this is possible?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not for security reasons. :(

Comment: Redirect means 302 status code. Do you mean that you want to add some custom headers to this response? It is on the target action that you are redirecting to that you probably want to add the headers, isn't it?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - in my scenario I am doing a POST-REDIRECT-GET. The information I want to add as a custom header is known only to the POSTed action, but not the GET one.

Comment: Then you are busted. Forget about it. The only thing you can hope is to add custom headers after the POST which is sending the 302 status code. You will have to change your architecture so that you perform the remote call in the target GET action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible for security reasons as specified above.

Comment: What kind of security reasons are you talking about? Could you improve your answer a little bit so you have real arguments to say so?